# Am I making synchronous call for this service and using that service properly in controller?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

My brother told me to write synchronous call for service, but the code below gives me an error. How can I do this correctly?

Here is my Angular service and Controller

```js
app.service("StateService", function ($http, $q) {
    var factory = $q.defer();
    factory.getStateData = function () {
        return $http.get("/State/GetStateData")
            .then(function (response) {
                factory.resolve(response.data);
                return factory.promise;
            }, function (response) {
                factory.reject(response);
                return factory.promise;
            }); 
    };
      factory.getCountryById = function (Id) {
        return $http.post('/Country/GetCountryById?Id=' + Id)
            .then(function (response) {
                factory.resolve(response.data);
                return factory.promise;
            }, function (response) {
                factory.reject(response);
                return factory.promise;
            });
    };
    };
    
    
app.controller("statecontroller", function ($scope, StateService, $http, $timeout) {    
    // get function
    $scope.GetStateData = function () {
        StateService.getStateData().then(function (d) {           
            $scope.States = d.data;
            $scope.fillAllData();
        }, function (response) {
            alert('error occurred' + response.data.ExceptionMesage);
        });
    };
    
    
    $scope.fillAllData = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.States.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.States[i].CountryId)
            {
                // var val = $scope.GetCountryById($scope.States[i].CountryId);
                var cName = "";
                var Id = $scope.States[i].CountryId;
                StateService.getCountryById(Id).then(function (d) {
                    if (d.data)
                        cName = d.data.CountryName;
                }, function (response) {
                    console.log('error occurred' + response.data.ExceptionMesage);
                });               
                $scope.States[i].CountryName = cName;
            }               
            else
                $scope.States[i].CountryName = null;
        }
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to make synchronous calls? Synchronous calls would halt the browser while waiting for the response and that's almost always never what you want. I reckon you actually mean asynchronous.

You may have misunderstood how services work. It's basically just a singleton object that gets injected by Angular. Additionally, the `$http`-service already creates promises for you so you could simplify your server drastically by writing it like this:

```
app.service("StateService", function ($http) {
    var service = this;

    service.getStateData = function () {
        return $http.get("/State/GetStateData");
    };

    service.getCountryById = function (Id) {
        return $http.post('/Country/GetCountryById?Id=' + Id);
    };
};
```

This should work perfectly fine with your implementation in the controller.

### Synchronous method - *but, really, don't do this*

```
app.service("StateService", function () {
    var service = this;

    service.getStateData = function () {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('GET', '/State/GetStateData', false);  // false makes it synchronous
        req.send(null);

        if (req.status === 200) {
            return req.responseText);
        }
    };

    ...
};
```

Then in your controller you consume it like this:

```
app.controller("statecontroller", function ($scope, StateService, $http, $timeout) {    
    // get function
    $scope.GetStateData = function () {         
        $scope.States = StateService.getStateData();
        $scope.fillAllData();
    };

    ...
});
```

All left then is to answer angry support calls from your users whos browser you're blocking the execution from.

**Also note that synchronous request may not work in all newer browsers:**

> Note: Starting with Gecko 30.0 (Firefox 30.0 / Thunderbird 30.0 /
>   SeaMonkey 2.27), synchronous requests on the main thread have been
>   deprecated due to the negative effects to the user experience.
>   *[From the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open)*

Yet another reason not to do this.

Comment: i did that but brother said to write synchronous call, i don't know why he said but i want to write it please help me, thanks for helping.

Comment: Don't listen to your brother. He's wrong. There's absolute no good reason to do this synchronously, based on your usage.